# Как построить приложение на ReactJS,чтобы оно без дополнительной прослойки работало с PostgresSQL?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, flux

Нужно сделать небольше приложение на `ReactJs+Flux`. Нужно,чтобы оно взаимодействовало с базой данных `Postgre SQL`. В качестве сборщика будет использоваться `Webpack`. Это приложение хочу реализовать без привлечения веб-фреймворков
Собственно вопрос касается архитектуры и порядка выполнения элементов приложения. Как сделать конфиг на вебпаке и собрать на нем реакт с flux нa webpack-dev-server(с reload) я понимаю, а вот как дальше увязать это дело с базой, мне не совсем ясно.Подскажите пожалуйста в каком порядке это реализуется,какие инструменты можно использовать,на что обратить внимание

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос конечно очень расплывчат, что значит *без дополнительной прослойки* непонятно.

Если вы хотите настольное приложение работающее с БД то можно завернуть ваш код во что то типа [nwjs](https://nwjs.io/). Там вам понадобится написать функции которые будут ходить в БД и будут доступны в виде DOM объектов в React приложении.

Comment: под прослойкой имелась в виду серверная часть,которая обычно реализуется с помощью фреймворков типа flask,django,zend,symphony.

Answer (score 0):

Я использую PostgREST в своих проектах, очень крутая вещь.
https://postgrest.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4/